# Can't get data from store to show up as the model

Tags: model, sencha-touch, store

I'm kinda new to Sencha Touch, so please bear with me.

At the app's launch i set the viewport to the viewport i use, and set all the views to the app namespace.

```
launch: function() {
        this.views.viewport = new this.views.Viewport();
        this.views.homecard = this.views.viewport.getComponent('home');
        this.views.usercard = this.views.viewport.getComponent('user');
        this.views.infocard = this.views.viewport.getComponent('info');
}
```

The viewport loads the home view first, and it is here i meet the problem.
This is my homecard:

```
ToolbarDemo.views.Homecard = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    title: "Meny",
    iconCls: "home",
    scroll: "vertical",
    bodyStyle: "background-color: #FFFFFF !important; background-image:                      url(images/background.png) !important; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:bottom left;",
    initComponent: function() 
    {
        ToolbarDemo.views.Homecard.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments); 
    },
    store:ToolbarDemo.stores.feedStorer,
    tpl:buttonTemplate,
    dockedItems: 
    [
        {
        xtype: "toolbar"
        }
    ],
    defaults: {height: "110px"},

});
```

Here's my template:

```
var buttonTemplate = new Ext.Template
(
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '   <div class="home_button_container">',
    '       <img class="home_button" src="{url_icon_large}" />',
    '       <p class="home_button_text">{name}</p>',
    '   </div>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```

Here's my model:

```
Ext.regModel('Feeds', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'url_icon_small', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'url_icon_medium', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'url_icon_large', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'url_icon_large_p', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'url', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'sort_order', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

Here's my store:

```
ToolbarDemo.stores.feedStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Feeds',
    storeId: 'feedStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'scripttag',
        url : 'http://localhost/webservice/feeds.php?username=' + sUsername + '&password=' + sPassword,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'feeds'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Here's the JSON:

> {"feeds":[{"name":"Links","url_icon_small":"http:url/link_small.png","url_icon_medium":"url/link_medium.png","url_icon_large":"url/link_large.png","url":"url/feed_content.php?type=link","sort_order":"1"}],"updated":[{"last_updated":"2011-06-09
>   11:15:47"}]}

The problem is that nothing shows on this view, and i suspect that it may be something wrong with the model? 
I've logged the store and i can see that it gets the data that it should.

Anyone got a suggestion to fix this?

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT** (Got tip about DataView):
Ext.Panel change:

```
ToolbarDemo.views.Homecard = new Ext.Panel({

    title: "Meny",
    iconCls: "home",
    scroll: "vertical",
    bodyStyle: "background-color: #FFFFFF !important; background-image: url(images/background.png) !important; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:bottom left;",
    initComponent: function() 
    {
        ToolbarDemo.views.Homecard.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments); 
    },
    dockedItems: 
    [
        {
        xtype: "toolbar"
        }
    ],
    defaults: {height: "110px"},
    items: new Ext.DataView(
    {
        tpl:buttonTemplate,
        store: ToolbarDemo.stores.feedStorer,
        autoHeight:true,
        multiSelect: true,
        loadingText: 'Laster data',
        itemSelector:'div.home_button_container',
        emptyText: 'No images to display'
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently setup to be handled by an `Ext.Dataview` and not an `Ext.Panel`. Anything inheriting form `Ext.Component` can be passed a `data` and `tpl` parameter and cause the body to be loaded with the result of passing the data into the tpl.

You however are using a `store` to handle the data which is not built into the `Ext.Panel` class. If you convert to an `Ext.Dataview` and define the required parameters necessary (it will throw errors when you try creating one without all the parameters necessary), then your template / panel will display properly.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. I tried to change it to a dataview and give tpl, store and itemSelector as i should, but it keeps giving me the errormessage: "Uncaught DataView requires tpl, store and itemSelector configurations to be defined.".   I have edited my first post, so you can see what i have done.

Comment: Have you tried setting the tpl parameter in your Ext.Dataview instantiation to be a blank string?

Comment: i had to move on, so i scrapped the DataView and tried something else